# How can i display the wordpress taxonomy image into front-end?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the taxonomy images into front-end, But I don't get how to use the code. Here I'm using a plugin **Taxonomy Images** [https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/] Please, can someone help me?

[image]

Here is my code below:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('category');
foreach($terms as $term):
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array($term->slug)
)
 ));
$tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($tag_query->have_posts()):
$image_url = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-url', '' );
echo '<li>
    ' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '
    <a href="#">'.esc_html($term->name).'</a> 
    <p>'.esc_html($term->description).'</p>
    </li>';
while($tag_query->have_posts()):$tag_query->the_post();
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: If you are using advanced custom field plugin then it will be very easy to do. do you want custom code to add image?

Comment: Dear **Dipmala**, I'm using Taxonomy images plugin here, can we solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Taxonomy image plugin then use `wp_get_attachment_image` method to get the image.
Below is complete code for you.

check below code this will help you.

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
print '<ul>';
foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {

    print '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '  <a href="#">'.esc_html($term->name).'</a> 
                        <p>'.esc_html($term->description).'</p></li>';
}
print '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Using only this code **'. wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) .'** didn't work for me dear **dipmala**, It will work only on this code below 


`$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'category',
) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    print '<ul>';
    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        print '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';
}`

Comment: share the plugin link

Comment: Dear **Dipmala**, Can we get any solution?

Comment: Great!! Thank you soo much dear **Dipmala**, Its working... But can we make it in a loop?, I need to display taxonomy images as an icon on each category along with name and description. Can we?

Comment: @Devbuddy if you noticed in above code i have displayed the name and description as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_get_attachment_image()` funxtion to show taxnomy images at front-end.

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' )
```

**Note:** Pass `image_id` in `wp_get_attachment_image()` function.

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235811/how-to-display-custom-taxonomy-images-on-index-php)

**Updated Answer:**

Yes, You can also get category `name` and `description` inside the loop.

```
$term->name
$term->description
```

Comment: Dear **Gufran**, In my case I'm trying to display name and description along taxonomy image in each loop. Can we solve it in any other way?

Comment: @Devbuddy, You can also get category `name` and `description` inside the loop.

    `$term->name` and ` $term->description`